# How to solve this trigonometric equalities?

Tags: trigonometry

We have to solve $ \tan(x) = 2 \sin(x)$ on $0 \leq x \leq 2 \pi$.

I rewrote it to $\sin(x) = \sin(2x)$ using $2\sin(x)\cos(x) = \sin(2x)$.

But how can I now find the set of solutions by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already reached at  $\sin2x=\sin x$

$\displaystyle\implies 2x=n\pi+(-1)^nx$ where $n$ is any integer

Deal the even and odd cases of $n$ separately

Comment: thanks, so it's unit circle stuff.

Comment: @Phaptitude, my pleasure. Is that hint sufficient for you?

Comment: Yes, it was sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just substitute $tan(x)=\frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}$ and then we have

$\frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}=2sin(x)\rightarrow sin(x)(\frac{1}{cos(x)}-2)=0$

Then $sin(x)=0$ or $cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}$

$sin(x)=0$ when $x=0$ or $x=\pi$ or $x=2\pi$ we have 3 solutions that belong to $[0,2\pi]$

and

$cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}\rightarrow cos(x)=cos(\frac{\pi}{3})$

$x=2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{3}$ or $x=2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}$ So we have 2 more solutions $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $2\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}$